# Typescript does not narrow down type parameter if it is dependent on another type parameter

Tags: typescript

We have this function that is part of a query abstraction. This function is used to query the related entities of an entity. It takes the type of the entity as the first argument and this type is used to constrain the second argument to the name of a relationship this entity has.

```
export interface Entities {
  user: UserEntity;
  accounts: AccountEntity
}

export interface UserEntity {
  relationships?: {
    accounts: AccountEntity[]
  };
}

export interface AccountEntity {
  relationships?: {
    user: UserEntity
    children: AccountEntity[]
    parent: AccountEntity
  };
}

export type RelationshipName<Entities extends Record<string, any>, T extends keyof Entities> = (
  Entities[T] extends { relationships?: infer Relationships }
  ? keyof Relationships
  : any
)

function relationshipOf<
 E extends keyof Entities, 
 R extends RelationshipName<Entities, T>
>(entityType: T,relationshipName: R) {
  return null
}
```

The thing is, when I pass the first argument to this function, e.g I pass `'account'` as the `entityType` argument, `E` changes from `keyof Entities` or `'account' | 'user'` to `'account'`. This is what we want because the type argument `R` now becomes `RelationshipName<Entities, 'account'>` because the `E` in `RelationshipName<Entities, E>` has been inferred to be `'account'`. So now we can only pass relationship names of the account entity as as the `relationshipName` argument. In other words, `R` has to extend `'children' | 'parent' | 'user'`.

The weird thing that I don't understand is this:
When I now pass, `'user'` as the `relationshipName` argument, the type of `R` does not behave in the same way as the `E` type parameter and "narrow" down to the actually passed value. It doesn't change from `'children' | 'parent' | 'user'` to `'user'`. It keeps being `'children' | 'parent' | 'user'`.

To show this in code, when I call the above function like this:

```
relationshipOf('account', 'user')
```

The type of the function gets inferred to this:

```
function relationshipOf<"account", "parent" | "children" | "user">(
  entityType: "account", 
  relationshipName: "parent" | "children" | "user"
): null
```

While I expected the type of this function to be inferred to this instead:

```
function relationshipOf<"account", "user">(
  entityType: "account", 
  relationshipName: "user"
): null
```

This behavior is quite surprising to me. There are some ways to work around this, but they don't really make sense to me.

#### Workaround 1: Cast the relationshipName to const

This workaround requires no changes in the function itself. Instead you have to cast the relationship to const when you pass it.

```
relationshipOf('account', 'user' as const)
```

#### Workaround 2: Intersect R with string

This workaround is really mysterious to me. I don't really know why this works.

```
function relationshipOf<
 E extends keyof Entities, 
 R extends RelationshipName<Entities, E>
>(entityType: E,relationshipName: R & string) {
  return null
}
```

---

I found that if, instead of having `RelationshipName` depend on `E`, when I pass a hardcoded entity type to `RelationshipName`, then the type of `R`  gets "narrowed" perfectly fine. This leads me to believe that the weird behaviour is caused by the dependency of `R` on `E`.

```
function relationshipOf<R extends RelationshipName<M, 'account'>>(relationship: R) {
  return null
}

relationshipOf('user') // type is: function relationshipOf<'user'>(relationship: 'user'): null
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening? Is it a bug? Next to that I would like to understand why the workarounds work. Expecially workaround 2 does not make sense to me.

[If you want to play around with it a bit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta&ssl=32&ssc=2&pln=27&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQgBNgAbAZzgG8AoOOAV3LQC44BVZqQk0gbjqMuAcygQGYNpzSjxYHmQH0c2cSnJsAgtlUMUC0jQC+NGqEixEKNFlwcuB6oKhlMMBBCTkAFgjDkAfjZaenomGTEJKRFI+WIyOAAfOCQGUn5BZR01GA04bV19eNIAbQBdQSMBEzNwaHhkVAwcPAKcxxC4F1I3Dy9ffyCnULhsX1IiFyQtbL0YA3KlUPCoPOluYsXK6tNzeqsm2zx12QkO51d3Tx8-QODMoTQ1h02yparjUxgATzA8RwAvHAANbAb4QdAEYrkAR7Sw-P5wABKlz6NzAADlMABbYAAHgMlFAqCQREoKNUUCIePIMCgyGEABo4JgkN8AHzMgAqcGJwFJlFB4MhhPZcCBAApBISSlyyryQCSydQuqjrgM7lZ0GhkWr+rc4CZ6AEQWCIbqeld9f5BGxWd8aABKUwAehdcC5vkonjwRAgwEoSAg8CQmCgYgA7nA-RGkMi4DAIAnvHgcDAGJh0t84GBMORmEQ4AA3TMMYA0dB6bBW1WWtEDADy6AAjHieXyBVDeMykQqleS9eisbiCdDuez2RKEcA2FzGd1euq-GwkY7hqr01A46l0p8aG6PV64D7o-7A2HI6fY-HE8nU9WM1mc3mC8XS+XK0hq31a4vrU2ACY2z7fllQMHsQM7FE6yXTEcXxQlx0nadZ3nQcBhXOAADI4FpekkGENdOhcTdtzSQwagPT0EG9JBfTPFILwgKMYzjXs8zgCMyFIZk-igbxMH8ZMaMQSgYBTUY8zwAAjYBsEwcJ4xEoN4BIP5SX5eBPA9Fk2WxaAPyrGsFytdEmwAZmAjswOKCDrIHGDrWHBCxzgAByFY3InKdfhnD00Mc9EVyIi5SJSci9wPTRKHBBhJLjZhgGZFMXDvBNfOfKB4KaJTA2DRjw2Y4BC1YhMkzclQcnINyaBM+s-CbZsJQAIhWZrmWayq5nIZrHQEA8MWYxAGnIWr0IalsWrajquvUZqWUoVQvBgPrXXdAAJNA8HE7aMtzLLcRy3tlKYriSuYuNbwq2Z1BqurYMAqauHauBOpu3Jev6jatrS6dMuynVjvPQqzqvS7ytm3I3IWzjuLGwLG3QcynrQF63sKD7VtMIA)